# Construct coordinates of $n+1$ points in ${\mathbb{R}^n}$, each pair of which have the same distance

Tags: linear-algebra

For example, if $n=2$ then we should construct a regular triangle. I think the sulution may be to extend one point in a step, finally giving $n+1$ points. But I havn't got any idea to extend one point with my linear algebra knowledge. Hope someone can provide a solution, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Consider points of the form $(0,\ldots,1,\ldots,0)\in\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ and construct a map from the hyperplane $\{(x_1,\ldots,x_{n+1})\colon x_1+\ldots+x_{n+1}=1\}$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$.